# Set Lookup and User Field Types when Migrating to Sharepoint online using Migration API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am in the process of writing a c# code to migrate set of files to Sharepoint online(o365) using migration API and I have successfully done migration using the approach mentioned in the below link.

http://case.schollaart.net/2016/03/10/office365-migration-using-c-sharp.html

But I am unable to update complex field types such as Lookup fields and User type fields in a document library.

Is there any suggestion or approach recommended for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint CSOM library to update lookup and person fields, please check this demo, Project is a lookup field and CurrentUser field is person field which is set to current user:

```
    using (var ctx = new ClientContext(@"http://sp2016/sites/test"))
    {

        var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("myList");
        var item = list.GetItemById(4);

        item["Title"] = "test";
        var currentUser = ctx.Web.CurrentUser;
        ctx.Load(item);
        ctx.Load(currentUser, user => user.Id);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        FieldUserValue uservalue = new FieldUserValue();
        uservalue.LookupId = currentUser.Id;
        item["CurrentUser"] = uservalue;
        FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue();
        lv.LookupId = 1;
        item["Project"] = lv;
        item.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Thing is that I need to get this done using Migration API so I can't use the code you have mentioned above. Migration API uses a Manifest package to do the migration. I need to create a Manifest xml as shown in the link I have provided in my question.